# How to view all fields in a database after clicking one data

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry I could not find words to describe my issue. May be you will understand.

Tools: PHP & MySQL

1. I have created a database with fields: CID, Name, DOB, Gender, EmailID.
   Data: 01, Kunal, 18.10.1988, Male, kunal@abc.com
2. I am able to display all/one data as required in a table.

   Example: Suppose I display only CID and Name.

   What i want: I would click on CID and it will show all informations(CID, Name, DOB, Gender, EmailID) in another new page with an option "ok".

Please suggest!!!

Regards,
Sourav

---

Hi, I am very new. I am not getting any clue. Can anyone help me with example (full source code). Say One page would just show CID and when clicked on the CID (say 1) it will open a new page with all information. Please anyone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's simple...

You create a table and you can fetch data with two simple query.
First , you should set the CID field as PrimaryKey.

Then, for creating links:

```
$query = "SELECT `CID`,`name` FROM `your_table`";
```

With this query result and a loop, you can make links with this format:

```
<a href="/second_page.php?id=1"></a>
<a href="/second_page.php?id=2"></a>
<a href="/second_page.php?id=3"></a>
...
```

In second_page.php you should do like this:

```
$cid = $_GET['id'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM `your_table` WHERE `CID`='". $cid ."'";
```

With second query you get one row of your_table.

If you newbie in MySql , first see:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp

Comment: You should cast a user-supplied `CID` to `int` to avoid SQL injection: `$cid = (int)$_GET['id'];`. Or better yet, test if it is a valid integer, and respond with a `404` or similar if not.

Comment: that is true, but I wanted to show the way and I didn't know he using mysql , mysqli or pdo !

Comment: Hi, I am very new. I am not getting any clue. Can anyone help me with example (full source code). Say One page would just show CID and when clicked on the CID (say 1) it will open a new page with all information. Please anyone can help me.